# Python (Tkinter): Unable to save user inputs to a variable using .get()

Tags: python, class, methods, tkinter

I am in the process of creating a UI using tkinter for a program I have written in Python2.7. I have modified code I found here: [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)

The way I was hoping the code would work is that when the "Apply" button is pressed, the method `varset1` or `varset2` (depending on the current page) would be called and this should save the user inputs to variables using the `.get()` command.

However, when I attempt to save the user inputted entries (Initial, LastName, HouseNo and PostCode) to variables, this error message is returned:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Here is a simplified version of my code, it is still a bit long, though this is as concise as I could make it in order to reproduce the error:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Setup(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (page1, page2):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("page1")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class page1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        tk.Label(self, text="First Initial: ").grid(row=2, sticky=tk.E)
        self.Initial = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=2, column=1)
        tk.Label(self, text="Last Name: ").grid(row=3, sticky=tk.E)
        self.LastName = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=3, column=1)

        Quit = tk.Button(self, text="Exit",
                         command= self.quit).grid(row=13, column=0, sticky="sw")
        Next = tk.Button(self, text="OK",
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame("page2")).grid(
                         row=13, column=1, sticky=tk.SE)
        Apply = tk.Button(self, text="Apply",
                          command = self.varset1).grid(row=13, column=1,
                          sticky=tk.SW)

    def varset1(self):
        initial = self.Initial.get()
        lastname = self.LastName.get()

class page2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        tk.Label(self, text="House Number: ").grid(row=2, sticky=tk.E)
        self.HouseNo = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=2, column=1)
        tk.Label(self, text="Post Code: ").grid(row=3, sticky=tk.E)
        self.PostCode = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=3, column=1)

        Quit = tk.Button(self, text="Exit",
                         command= self.quit).grid(row=13, column=0, sticky="sw")
        Back = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame("page1")).grid(
                         row=13, column=1, sticky=tk.SE)
        Apply = tk.Button(self, text="Apply",
                          command = self.varset2).grid(row=13, column=1,
                          sticky=tk.SW)

    def varset2(self):
        houseno = self.HouseNo.get()
        postcode = self.PostCode.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Setup()
    app.mainloop()
```

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: a basic search of the error message would have given you an answer. Please do a little research before posting questions. Also, you really only need about half a dozen lines of code to reproduce this particular error.

Comment: I did a lot of searching, though due to my obvious lack of programming experience, I unfortunately couldn't see the relation between those answers and my particular case. I would not be lazy enough to request the help of the kind people on the forum if I believed my question had already been answered. This is all a learning experience and I can appreciate why you would write this comment.

Comment: @BryanOakley And with regards to the code needing only a dozen lines to reproduce the error, again, this is due to my obvious lack of programming experience. Hopefully, with more time and experience I will be able to produce more concise code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every variables you made to assign `Entry` and `Button` are grided using this format:

```
self.Initial = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=2, column=1)
```

which is wrong because `tk.Entry(self)` returns the Entry object, but `tk.Entry(self).grid(row=2, column=1)` returns `None`. So `self.Initial` is actually None. What you need to do is to split it into two lines like this for every `Entry` or `Button` that you're going to retrieve data from:

```
self.Initial = tk.Entry(self)
self.Initial.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

You should change every one of those for connivance and to avoid further similar errors(which is what you should've done in the first place)...

```
self.LastName = tk.Entry(self).grid(row=3, column=1)
# into:
self.LastName = tk.Entry(self)
self.LastName.grid(row=3, column=1)
# and so on....
```

Comment: This resolved my issue, thank you very much for your quick response!